# Clickable Menu Dropdown in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I am finishing up a WordPress website (https://saltypack.com.au/) that I made using the theme Neve. The last issue I am having is for the hamburger mobile Menu, I have "Services" as a dropdown menu and there is no Services page. On desktop, you can hover "Services" and the dropdown appears. On mobile, you have to click the arrow icon for the dropdown to appear and clicking "Services" does nothing. I want both the arrow and "Services" to be clickable.

Comment: .caret-wrap class assign to it's parent li, i think you solve your problem that way

Answer (score 1):

Set the `.caret-wrap` to be:

```
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
```

Then set `.caret svg` to be:

```
margin-left: auto;
```